# Angular forRoot()

Tags: angular, routes

I have a `forRoot` method, however when I go to the designated address I don't get what the component has inside. Why? How does `forRoot` work?

It's my app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/register.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    /*RouterModule.forRoot([
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
    { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },*/
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'test', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'account/register', component: RegisterComponent }
], { relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy' })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Have you had a look at: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule
Not sure if this is what you are asking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can find out what `RouterModule.forRoot` does on the Angular [website](http://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule)

or if you are interested in the code you can see that on the [Angular Git repo](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router_module.ts).

Comment: I had to use <router-outlet>. Thanks!